# The route params is empty

Tags: angular

I have the following user template file which contains tab control

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>              
          <a class="tab-label" md-tab-link [routerLink]="'following'" routerLinkActive #following="routerLinkActive" [active]="following.isActive">
            Following
          </a>
```

and the following app.route config

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: 'user/:id', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
},
```

and the following user.route config

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: '', component: UserComponent,
    children: [

        { path: 'following', loadChildren: './following/following.module#FollowingModule' }            
    ]
}
```

];

The problem is that I want to get the id in the "following" component like this:

```
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.error(params);
        });
```

but params is always empty.

Do I need to specify the id param in the user.route somehow?

I also tried calling the parent like this but the params is still empy...

```
this.subRoute = this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {

            console.log(params);
});
```

Comment: Can you past here an example of URL that you're trying?

Comment: Hi @developer033 here is an example http://localhost:3000/user/5836aadf7911f7725ce3cd2b/following

Comment: Hi, my solution is working. please add your plunker url here.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to specify the id param in the user.route somehow?

Yes, you need to specify the parameter in *path*:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '', component: UserComponent,
  children: [    
    { 
      loadChildren: './following/following.module#FollowingModule',
      path: ':parent_id/following' // <- Here
    }
  ]
}
```

So, *somewhere* in ***"following" component***:

```
const parentId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('parent_id');
```

**PS:** I'm assuming that you have a config route like this (in ***"following" component***):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    component: FollowingComponent, path: ''
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @developer033 thanks for your suggestion. However if I add the parent_id I am routing to the root probably because app.routes already defineds :id parameter which is needed in the parent as well.

Comment: Hey, I didn't understand what you're saying.. have you tested my solution?

Comment: Yes, so I have everything set like you suggest. Additionally I have the path: 'user/:id', in the app.routes. Now if I navigate to http://localhost:3000/user/5836aadf7911f7725ce3cd2b/following it navigates to the http://localhost:3000 probably because it does not find any match. If I remove the  parent_id from path: ':parent_id/following' it works fine

Comment: But `parent_id` just an alias to the parameter, you can name it whatever you like... Can you edit your question to include the routes of "following" *component*?

Comment: Yes, I have it like this  { path: ':id/following', loadChildren: './following/following.module#FollowingModule' }, in the user.route but it does not navigate to /user/5836aadf7911f7725ce3cd2b/following unless I remove the :id parameter

Comment: Sorry here you go const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: FollowingComponent }
];

Comment: ...and @NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES),

Answer (score 1):

use this to route:

```
this.router.navigate(['/productlist'], { queryParams: { filter: JSON.stringify(this.product) } });
```

and in another component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
.
.
.
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
         this.route
          .queryParams
          .subscribe(params => {
                let filterParam = JSON.parse(params['filter']);
                console.log(filterParam);
           });
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe he needed the critic badge at SO

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this doesn't seem like it addresses the question, and just provides an ugly workaround. Nobody wants a JSON in the route.